# Subtract value at a set interval?

Tags: php, javascript

I'd like to have a php function which will deduct a value, say, 50 from an initial integer of say, 500 at a set interval.

For example: Every 30 days, deduct 50 from 500. So after 90 days, you are left with 350, etc.

I can do subtractions, it's the interval routine that I can't figure out.

If not PHP, JS is great too. This is used to count down a value from the beginning of the year, to the end.

Comment: What's your actual goal here? You probably don't need to actually subtract the value every 30 days, you just need to calculate the value it should have when you need it, taking into account how many days have passed since (start date).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? You want a function that when run...subtracts 50 from some number every 30 (real life) days .. ? If not, could you further specify your function? e.g. it takes in an integer (500), a value to deduct (50), and interval (30 days -- a datetime? integer), and a number of days (90 -- a datetime? integer), and you want it to return 350??

Comment: You can't do that with PHP as it is a one-shot script. You'll need something like Cron tasks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cron+job+php

Comment: The idea here is this: On a "sales" page, I'd have a dollar amount, say, $600. So the sentence reads, 'a savings of $600'. The user would see this displayed in January. In february, they would see $550, since each month represents a $50 deduction of the total. March, they would see $500, April, $450, until December kicks around, and they see $50 left as the 'savings'. So every 30 days (or whatever the internal is), the value is reduced by $50.

Comment: @ldiqual it's easily possibly, just not quite the way he explains it.

Comment: @deceze not quite, and very rigid.

Comment: @Jon Just demonstrating the basic approach, which the OP is obviously missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a starting number, and you trying to figure out what your current value is. Its a basic total - (time pass * decrement) problem.

So example, You have your original time.

```
$originalDate = '2011-01-01';
$now = '2011-03-01';

//it will count no. of days
$dateDiff=(strtotime($now) - strtotime($originalDate))/ (60 * 60 * 24);

$startingValue = 500;
$descrement = 50;

$currentValue = $startingValue - ($dateDiff/30*$descrement);
```

Comment: I tested both functions, and modified this one slightly.

`$originalDate = '2012-01-01';

 $dateDiff=(strtotime("now") - strtotime($originalDate))/ (60 * 60 * 24);

 $startingValue = 588;
 $descrement = 49;

 $currentValue = $startingValue - ($dateDiff/30*$descrement);
  
 echo $currentValue;
 echo "<br>";
 echo round($currentValue, -1);`

Right now it's giving me an exact value, using round, of 470 which for the middle of the month makes sense. Ideally, this number would be fixed, so for March, it would be 490 (588-49-49).

Comment: This solution worked well for my needs. Ive modified it to an extend, but the functionality is there.

Answer (score 0):

if you want this in a function:

```
/* deduct()
 *
 * @param $start        - the starting amount to subtract from
 * @param $amount       - the amount to subtract by
 * @param $interval     - the interval between deductions
 * @param $current_time - the current time to measure against the interval
 *
 * @return the amount after deduction $amount
 *           every $interval from $start until $current_time
 */
function deduct($start, $amount, $interval, $current_time) {
  return $start - ($amount * floor($current_time / $interval));
}
```

You can easily pass in a time value using `time()`, or something like that, formatted into your unit of time.

Comment: Having some difficulty setting this up, in the sense that while I can feed in the fixed values, I'm not sure the calculation is processing for me. It might be due to the time output I am using, or maybe I should leave it in the default format. I'm actually not getting a return value.

Comment: Make sure the date is in the proper format. Use `date('d', time())` to format it for days.